# showing column data as header in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like:

```
-------------------
id  class name      sub 
------------------------
1   mca   aditya    network
2   mca   abhishek  daa
3   mca   akhilesh  algorithm
4   btech ram       cs
5   btech shyam     ds
6   btech anand     client/server
7   mba   furqan    os
8   mba   arvind    marketing
9   mba   aayush    hr
```

I want a result set like the following:

```
----------------
class    name      sub
------------------------
mca      aditya    network
         abhishek  daa
         akhilesh  algorithm
btech    ram       cs
         shyam     ds
         anand     client/server
mba      furqan    os
         arvind    marketing
         aayush    hr
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be better off handling this in your UI / Display tier, but if you need the query to do it in SQL 2008, you can use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
WITH ordered AS
(
   SELECT t.class, t.name, t.sub
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.class ORDER BY t.Name ASC) AS RowNumber
   FROM myTable AS t
)
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN o.RowNumber = 1 THEN o.class
          ELSE ''
       END AS class
   , o.name, o.sub
FROM ordered AS o
```

I'm not sure what sort / order you're looking for.  Your example appears to still be ordered by Id.  If you want this, you can add the Id column into the `ordered CTE` and then add `ORDER BY o.Id ASC` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Adam's answer will work, but the most correct part of his answer is

> you may be better off handling this in your UI / Display tier

What you are trying to do is - to put it bluntly - wrong.  The below says, for example, that `aditya` has class `mca`, but `abhishek` and `akhilesh` don't have a class.

```
class    name      sub 
--------------------- 
mca      aditya    network          
         abhishek  daa          
         akhilesh  algorithm 
btech    ram       cs              
         shyam     ds
         anand     client/server
```

Is it true that `abhishek` and `akhilesh` don't have a class? Of course not.

So if I have an application that calls this stored procedure or view and looks at this resultset, how am I supposed to know which class `shyam` belongs to? You can't say 'it's btech because that's the last class mentioned', because how do you know which order the results are viewed? You have no `order by` in your query.

Comment: I've seen at least one other similar question before.  When I did, it looks like the OP in both cases wants to use SQL to develop reports with.  I suspect that this will be printed off and shows to management, but it is only a guess.